# Replace symbol with numerical value

Tags: replacement

How do I get the same result, i.e., how can I get *Mathematica* to replace `a` with 1?

```
b = a;

s1[a_?NumericQ] := Sin[a]

s2[a_?NumericQ] := Sin[b]

s1[1.]

s2[1.]
```

I appreciate any help !

The nearest real problem I want to esolver is as follows:

b = a;

```
sua[a_?NumericQ] := NDSolveValue[{
   D[u[x, t], t] + D[u[x, t], x] == -b u[x, t],

   u[x, 0] == 1,

   u[0, t] == 1},

  u,

  {x, 0, 1},

  {t, 0, 5}]

sua[1][1, 5]
```

I would like a solution without the replacement `/. b -> a`?

Comment: `s2[a_?NumericQ] := Sin[b] /. b -> a` or just `s2[a_?NumericQ] := Sin[a]`, can you explain what you need more?

Comment: I do not want sibstituir directly "b" for "a". Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The following will do what you ask, but I really can't think how it can be useful in any practical situation.

```
a = 42.;
b := a;  (* note use of SetDelayed *)
s1[a_?NumericQ] := Sin[a]
s2[a_?NumericQ] := Sin[b]
```

Now `b` tracks `a` and has value 42. at top-level. Therefore, for any numerical argument given `s2`, say `π`,

```
Sin[42.] == s2[π]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

To make `s2` evaluate to value other than `Sin[42.]`, `a` must be given a value different from 42. I will do this in a dynamically-scoped block, preventing `b` from being disturbed at top-level.

```
Table[{s1[u], Block[{a = u}, s2[π]]}, {u, .1, .3, .1}]
```

> ```
> {{0.0998334, 0.0998334}, {0.198669, 0.198669}, {0.29552, 0.29552}}
> ```

`b` is, of course, unchanged at top-level.

```
b
```

> ```
> 42.
> ```

However, consider that

```
s3[___] := Sin[b]
```

has the same behavior as `s2` as is shown by

```
Table[{s1[u], Block[{a = u}, s3[]]}, {u, .1, .3, .1}]
```

> ```
> {{0.0998334, 0.0998334}, {0.198669, 0.198669}, {0.29552, 0.29552}}
> ```

so I don't see why you want to define something like `s2`.

has